# mu4e-xxxx-folder evaluates to nil

Tags: mu4e

I'm trying to abstract elisp code for my dynamic folders on mu4e but for some reason executing a command fails with `mu4e-error: [mu4e] mu4e-xxxx-folder evaluates to nil`, here is the current code:

```
  (setf shackra/mu4e-maildir-dirs '("yahoo" "kue" "gmail"))
  (defun shackra/mu4e-find-maildir (msg place &optional alternative)
    (if msg
        (let ((msg-maildir (mu4e-message-field msg :maildir)))
          (dolist (maildir shackra/mu4e-maildir-dirs)
            (when (string-match-p (concat "^/" maildir) msg-maildir)
              (concat "/" maildir "/" place))))
      (if alternative
          alternative
        (dolist (maildir shackra/mu4e-maildir-dirs)
          (when (string-match-p maildir user-mail-address)
            (concat "/" maildir "/" place))))))
  (setf mu4e-sent-folder ;; carpeta de enviados
        (lambda (msg)
          (shackra/mu4e-find-maildir msg "Sent")))
  (setf mu4e-drafts-folder ;; carpeta de borradores
        (lambda (msg)
          (shackra/mu4e-find-maildir msg "Drafts")))
  (setf mu4e-trash-folder ;; carpeta de correo borrado
        (lambda (msg)
          (shackra/mu4e-find-maildir msg "Trash" "/gmail/Trash")))
  (setf mu4e-refile-folder ;; carpeta de correo salvado
        (lambda (msg)
          (shackra/mu4e-find-maildir msg "Archive" "/gmail/Archive")))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was getting my own code wrong. My assumption was that the execution flow would stop inside the `when` clause, in reality code stops at the end of the function definition, thus returning `nil`

I changed my function to this:

```
  (setf shackra/mu4e-maildir-dirs '("yahoo" "kue" "gmail"))
  (defun shackra-mu4e-get-maildir (maildir place)
    "Retorna ubicación para mover el mensaje por MAILDIR a otro lugar PLACE."
    (let ((maildir-path))
      (dolist (dir shackra/mu4e-maildir-dirs)
        (when (string-match-p (concat "^/" dir) maildir)
          (setf maildir-path (concat "/" dir "/" place))))
      (unless maildir-path
        (setf maildir-path (mu4e-ask-maildir-check-exists "Mover el mensaje al maildir: ")))
      maildir-path))
```

and used it like this:

```
  (setf mu4e-sent-folder ;; carpeta de enviados
        (lambda (msg)
          (shackra-mu4e-get-maildir (or (mu4e-message-field msg :maildir) "") "Sent")))
  (setf mu4e-drafts-folder ;; carpeta de borradores
        (lambda (msg)
          (shackra-mu4e-get-maildir (or (mu4e-message-field msg :maildir) "") "Drafts")))
  (setf mu4e-trash-folder ;; carpeta de correo borrado
        (lambda (msg)
          (shackra-mu4e-get-maildir (or (mu4e-message-field msg :maildir) "") "Trash")))
  (setf mu4e-refile-folder ;; carpeta de correo salvado
        (lambda (msg)
          (shackra-mu4e-get-maildir (or (mu4e-message-field msg :maildir) "") "Archive")))
```